# Reduce space between checkbox and title in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to remove the space between checkbox and title but i cant able to reduce the space

here is my code

```
                      Expanded(
                      //width: 30,

                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                          checkColor: Colors.white,
                          activeColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
                          title: Text('Select All',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.black)),
                          value: _selectAll,
                          dense: true,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                          onChanged: (bool value) {
                          
                              }
                            }
                        
                            setState(() {});
                          }),
                    ),
```

here is the image how it is coming

[image]

How to reduce the space

Comment: `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),`, make the `10` in `.fromLTRB` a smaller number maybe?

Comment: NO its not reducing even if i give 0

Comment: Then I don't think that is possible. You will have to create a custom widget`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom widget in order to resolve your problem, because if you're using the CheckboxListTile the way it is, you're gonna have to add more contentPadding to your widget in order to make the gap smaller and by default, I see that it has a default padding between the actual checkbox and the text widget ... I personally, don't know why you're trying to squeeze more space from this thing, because in documentation it says clearly that CheckboxListTile acts just like a ListTile, which in my knowledge it takes all the space available in a row and the padding between items in your widget will be a little bit bigger. Also your widget is wrapped in an Expanded widget which also take the whole space available. So in conclusion you either use it as the way it is intended, or you can create a custom widget that will bennefit your problems.